# Java Canvas err focus or action listener in second window

Tags: java, focus, awt, java-canvas, bufferstrategy

I create 2 Frames:

in 1st - I make a Button which move me to 2nd Frame created by class which extends after Canvas and after the move from 1st Frame to 2nd I lose the action listener or focus

1st window here :

```
public class Credits extends JFrame {

public Credits() {
    super("Credits");
    setSize(300, 200);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JButton ok = new JButton("GAME");


    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    this.add(ok);
    setVisible(true);


    ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            dispose();
            new WojnaSwiatow().game();

        }
    });



}

public static void main(String []args ) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
           new Credits();
        }

    });
}
}
```

Second Frame:

```
public class WojnaSwiatow extends Canvas implements Stage, KeyListener {/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

    createBufferStrategy(2);
    strategia = getBufferStrategy();
    requestFocus();

    requestFocusInWindow(true);
    addKeyListener(this);
    okno.addKeyListener(this);
    okno.pack();
    okno.setVisible(true);



public long usedTime;
public BufferStrategy strategia;
private SpriteCache spriteCache;
private ArrayList actors;
private Player player;


public WojnaSwiatow(){

    spriteCache = new SpriteCache();
    JFrame okno = new JFrame("..:Wojna Swiatow :..");
    JPanel panel = (JPanel)okno.getContentPane();
    setBounds(0,0,Stage.SZEROKOSC,Stage.WYSOKOSC);

    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Stage.SZEROKOSC,Stage.WYSOKOSC));
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.add(this);

    okno.setBounds(0,0,Stage.SZEROKOSC,Stage.WYSOKOSC);
    okno.setVisible(true);
    okno.setResizable(false);
    okno.setLocationRelativeTo(null);


    okno.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```

maybethe problem is on bufferstrategy ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"I create 2 Frames:"*  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)